# Sencha Touch Menu doesn't display in generated Cordova project if menu is not in config

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I found that if I dynamically create a menu inside initialize event on a TabPanel, the menu will not be created/added in generated Cordova project.

A workaround is I put the menu in items of the TabPanel, but then the menu pops up even I don't ask so and it will always display the menu in the bottom of the screen even I have already specified the side:'left'

Here is the code （inside the initialize event）:

```
var menu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
     items: [
         {
             text: 'Settings',
             iconCls: 'settings'
         },
         {
             text: 'New Item',
             iconCls: 'compose'
         },
         {
             text: 'Star',
             iconCls: 'star'
         }
     ]
 });

 Ext.Viewport.setMenu(menu, {
     side: 'left',
     reveal: true
 });
```

### Update

I have updated my code in Sencha Fiddle, see: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/6hr

Also, menu cannot be added by using add() method, it has to be added by using setMenu(), tested and confirmed. See the Fiddle code.

Comment: have you inspected the DOM to see if the menu gets added?

Comment: hi @shepsii yes, I did. I inspected the Sencha touch project and found the menu component in the Components panel, but found it is missed in the generated Cordova project

Comment: I don't think setMenu is a real method. You are just setting a field in your JS object called 'menu' and putting your `Ext.Menu` in it. You should use the `add` function to add a view to your viewport.

Comment: the components panel in the sencha inspector is a different thing than the DOM.

Comment: hi @shepsii yes, I understand that. I compared both projects within Sencha Component Inspector.

Comment: hi @Saffron, I don't understand why you don't think setMenu is a real method. I found it in example code and here is its document : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Viewport-method-setMenu  So do you mean something like: Ext.Viewport.add(menu)? if so, how do I specify which side the menu should be put on?

Comment: hi @Saffron I have tried your way, it doesn't work. See my updated sencha fiddle to see what will happen by using add() method(which isn't supposed to be used in this situation). You can uncomment my code to see how the setMenu() works.